# How to structure my DB to account for yearly differences & changes to column names

Tags: mysql, database, server, schema

Every year I receive a flat file return from 7 different sources containing data that I need to centralise.

Although the return contains the same data from each source, they have different column names, some have additional columns which need discarding, and some use different data types to represent the same data (1&0 Vs Boolean etc)

I have to go through each return and standardise them so they all 'match' what is required in my central table. Historically I have a view created for each source that standardises the return to the correct format & then run a script which copies the data from the view in to my final table where I can now run queries against the dataset as a whole, across sources and years.

So my problem is that for each return that I receive, I need to create a new union and select in the view that accounts for the yearly changes.

I will attempt to illustrate with a small example:

*Source1_Year1
*Source1_Year2
*Source1_year3

*Final_Data

Each of these returns had the same 50 columns, a majority named the same & holding the data as needed - however across the 3 years the data within the column person_category has changed naming convention from using data like 'cat1, cat2, cat3' to 'type1, type2, type3' to 'c1, c2, c3'.

so in the view for Source1 I must standardise this column so it falls in line with what's required in the table Final_Data.

It just seems a little overkill to have 3 different unioned select statements, where the select is 95% the same.

Currently my view for a given source looks like:

```
select 
    source, year, name, lastname, age,
    case when person_category = 'type1' then '1'
       when person_category - 'type2' then '2'
       when person_category - 'type2' then '3'
       end as person_cat'
from Source_Year1
Union All
select 
    source, year, name, lastname, age
    case when person_category = 'cat1' then '1'
       when person_category - 'cat2' then '2'
       when person_category - 'cat3' then '3'
       end as person_cat'
from Source_Year2
Union All
select 
    source, year, name, lastname, age,
    case when person_category = 'c1' then '1'
       when person_category - 'c2' then '2'
       when person_category - 'c3' then '3'
       end as person_cat'
from Source_Year3
```

As you can see: columns source, year, name, lastname and age are selected 3 times, I'm looking for a way to minimise this. It's ok for a small example but in reality these tables have 50 columns of which 45 don't need changing and view is just massive as the select statement is repeated so many times.

Comment: It is hard for me to visualize your data.  Can you pare down your question to something minimal?

Comment: What do you actually do with this data? Obviously this is not only about archiving, for otherwise you could simply store the files in a filesystem and be done with it. So you want to query the data? Although there are columns you do not know? Then maybe just store what you know and are interested in and remain oblivious to the other data?

Comment: I have altered the question slightly to help visualise my issue. It is about minimising the amount of times I am using the same large select script with very small differences and how to 'un-bulk' my approach. Yes I will need to query the data & aggregate across sources and years.

Comment: Load the data into a single table.  If you are processing the data anyway, you might as well complete the processing.